# What is the most effective way to learn mathematical notation?

Tags: notation

Sometimes i read textbooks and cant understand what the symbols are saying, I google the symbol im still lost. The most recent example is when i tried to understand generating functions and came across this:

"The symbol f <-ops-> {an}<sub>0</sub><sup>∞</sup> means that the series f is the ordinary
power series (‘ops’) generating function for the sequence {an}<sub>0</sub><sup>∞</sup>. That
is, it means that f = $\sum\limits_{n=1}^{}$
a<sub>n</sub>x<sup>n</sup>."
(Herbert S. Wilf, *Generatingfunctionology* 2nd edition, 1994, page 33)

I eventually understood what the notation meant but it took 10 minutes just to decipher and it happens very often. So i was wondering if there was a way to bolster my ability's to read mathematical proofs or if there is a simple glossary that i can use to not get bogged down.

When i can translate the notation to English i understand the concepts well but it takes a long time to do so. When i try to understand a topic and have to rely on external resources (not my main textbook or find help online) I typically run into notation im not familiar with. Sometimes I need literal hours to read someone else's explanation just because of notation and often times after i can put the symbols to words it takes me a fraction of the time to understand what they are saying.

Comment: Usually, a good textbook has an Index listing the symbols used and every new symbol is defined/described the first time it is introduced.

Comment: Which part(s) of that quote gave you trouble? Generatingfunctionology definitely assumes you've seen and are comfortable with summation notation, so I wonder if it's a question of prereqs.

Comment: my starting point was off a discrete math course and it used different methodology (http://discrete.openmathbooks.org/dmoi3/dmoi.html). it covers some of the things but not in the same way